# How to Get docusign completed envelope

Tags: docusignapi

i am hitting the below 
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/4636543/search_folders/completed?include_recipients=true
but getting 0 result set size even i have 1 completed envelope.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not specifying a `from_date`, the call should only return envelopes from the last 30 days.

If that's not the issue, please provide an API trace of what was actually sent and receive. Note that you should **edit** your existing question to add the additional information.

[How to trace](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) docs.

Also, if you want the completed envelopers, I'd suggest using the 
[Envelopes::listStatusChanges](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/) call instead.